# Como remover ruidos de imagem usando opencv - python?

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou trabalhando com imagens de pele, no reconhecimento de manchas de pele, e devido a presença de ruidos, principalmente pela presença de pelos, fica mais complicado este trabalho.

Tenho um exemplo de imagem no qual eu trabalho na tentativa de destacar somente a mancha da pele, mas devido a grande quantidade de pelos, o algoritmo nao é efetivo. Com isso, gostaria que me ajudassem a desenvolver um algoritmo para a remoçao ou diminuir a quantidade de pelos e assim poder destacar somente minha area de interesse(ROI), que sao as manchas.

Algoritmo usado para destacar as manchas da pele:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#Read the image and perform threshold
img = cv2.imread('IMD006.bmp')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Search for contours and select the biggest one
contours, hierarchy =     cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

#Create a new mask for the result image
h, w = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h, w), np.uint8)

#Draw the contour on the new mask and perform the bitwise operation
cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt],-1, 255, -1)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

#Display the result
cv2.imwrite('IMD006.png', res)
#cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Exemplo de imagem usada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saida:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O algoritmo se comporta como esperado para imagens sem pelos, como se ver abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como tratar esses ruidos a ponto de melhorar a minha regiao de interesse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solução

- Criação da máscara com:

  - `morphologyEx` com `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE`
  - `cv2.blur` para borrar a imagem
  - Binarização com a flag `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU`
  - Floodfill para eliminar os cantos da máscara
- Recortar da imagem original o encontrado pela máscara, com lógica AND
- Canny Edges para encontrar os fios cabelo e depois dilatação
- Retira da imagem recortada o encontrado pelo Canny Edges, com lógica OR
- Utilização a interpolação Inpaint de Alexandru Telea para preencher os espaços vazios, prevendo o que deveria estar naquele local vazio.

### Código de Exemplo

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import urllib.request


# Abrir a imagem do link ou img = cv2.imread(diretorio_da_imagem//nome_do_arquivo)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgW91.png")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)

# Utilização do morphologyEx e blur
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernel, iterations = 2)
blur = cv2.blur(closing,(15,15))

# Binarização
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, mask = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('Binarização',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Preenche os quatro cantos da imagem binária
w, h = mask.shape[::-1]
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, (0, 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, (w-1, 0), 0)
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, (0, h-1), 0)
cv2.floodFill(mask, None, (w-1, h-1), 0)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Lógica AND para obter da imagem original a encontrada pela criação do mask
img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask )
cv2.imshow('AND',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Canny Edges
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100,200)
dilate = cv2.dilate(edges,kernel,iterations=1)
dilate = cv2.bitwise_not(dilate)
cv2.imshow('Canny',dilate)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Lógica OR para retirar da imagem original os pêlos encontrados
img = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=dilate )
cv2.imshow('Edges',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

#Interpolação da imagem para preencher os vazios
dilate = cv2.bitwise_not(dilate)
inpaint = cv2.inpaint(img, dilate, 3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imshow('InPaint', inpaint)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### Resultados

#### Binarização

[image: Binarização]

#### Floodfill

[image: floodfill]

#### Lógica AND

[image: Lógica And]

#### Canny Edges

[image: Canny Edges]

#### Lógica OR

[image: Lógica OR]

#### Interpolação Inpaint

[image: Inpaint]